# MVC3: Access a property of an Object in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

in an ASP.NET MVC3 web application.

I have a view. the view has a IEnumerable model.

I need to loop through all the model's items and show the item.Name

**The view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Object> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <div class="itemName">@item.Name</div>
}
```

In the controller, I use Linq to entities to get the list of objects from the database.

**The Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Object> AllPersons = GetAllPersons();
    return View(AllSurveys);
}

public IEnumerable<Object> GetAllPersons()
{
    var Context = new DataModel.PrototypeDBEntities();
    var query = from p in Context.Persons
                select new
                {
                    id = p.PersonsId,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

When I run I get this error:

```
 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I access the "Name" Property of the model items?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a strong type for your method return.

```
public class MyObject {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<MyObject> GetAllPersons() 
{ 
    var Context = new DataModel.PrototypeDBEntities(); 
    var query = from p in Context.Persons 
                select new MyObject
                { 
                    id = p.PersonsId, 
                    Name = p.Name, 
                    CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate 
                }; 
    return query;
}
```

... Then update your view to reflect the new model ...

```
@model IQueryable<MyObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to define a class `Person`, and to change your model/controller to work with `IEnumerable<Person>` instead of object.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do an explicit `Casting`

```
@(string) item.Name
```

or use `dynamic` type.

In the view, Change

```
@model IEnumerable<Object>
```

to

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but you might try to use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IEnumerable<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Your model type is `IEnumerable<Object>`, change it to `IEnumerable<Person>` so that you can access `Person` properties.